# Can I call the following "irony"?

Tags: word-usage

> So how did I become interested in animal suicide? **Ironically**, it began
>   with my own death wish.

I'm not really sure whether I can call this irony, since irony usually refers to the contrast between two opposite things. If this isn't irony, what should I call it, then?

Comment: I think you can call it irony if you want to  express the idea that your own attitude to suicide has given rise to your interest for  that of animals. Ironically,  studying   animal suicide  you  seem to have  found a cure for yourself;  you are still alive!!

Comment: Coincidentally, it began...

Comment: Paradoxically, it began...

Comment: No paradox *at all* @ErikKowal

Comment: @itsbruce - Because...?

Comment: Because there is no logical contradiction.  You *justify* paradox - none seems apparent.

Comment: Sure there's a paradox -- a shrink for the OP and a vet for the animal.

Comment: (While some might quibble with use of "ironically" above, it's precisely that -- quibbling over meaningless distinctions.  Only a language lawyer would read the sentence and take issue with it.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Do language lawyers have something to do with grammar nazis?

Comment: @janoChen - They're the same, only with briefcases instead of hobnail boots.

Comment: semantics exist for a reason, and that Alanis Morissette song is so *ignorant*. Most of what she says is *ironic* is actually *tragic*. So no this is not about *meaningless distinctions*, it is about exactly the *opposite*, **semantics**. `Ironic` does not equal `Tragic` or `Unfortunate` or `Coincidence` unless you are willfully ignorant of what the words actually mean and do not care about being a fool.

Comment: @HotLicks [Jetskiing with chinchillas](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/irony) is always 100 times more fun than considering the definition of irony!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you stated, irony is typically featured to draw attention to a contrast, and while it can have varied uses, most of them revolve around saying something one doesn't mean or reversing some kind of expectation.

In the sentence you gave, the idea of being interested in suicide arising from personal, suicidal thoughts should not be surprising or unexpected to the reader, though perhaps not so much as to warrant the use of "expectedly". The connection is certainly interesting, and the use of "interestingly" or "interestingly enough" could work to point out the unusual circumstance. But in the end, that comes down to artistic license.

If the first sentence showed an interest in animal health care, resuscitation, or resurrection, irony would aptly describe the contrast between that and suicidal thoughts, but since the two things are closely and understandably linked, irony doesn't seem to be a solid fit.

One commenter suggests coincidentally, but I disagree, as coincidence describes "when something uncanny, accidental and unexpected happens" or when there is no obvious connection other than time.

Further reading:
http://thatsnotironic.com/ - Turns various definitions and pitfalls and turns makes them digestible.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irony - Basic definition that could help.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Misuse - More common pitfalls

Comment: So, which word would you suggest?

Comment: [Coincidence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincidence) means happening at the same time, too. It doesn't have to be unexpected, but then again, the tendency to use the word "irony" similarly implies an unexpected but related event that contrasts with the current event. Note that thatsnotironic.com points at irony being both coincidental *and* contradictory...

Comment: @SrJoven Jeez, I checked all those links and other stuff. I still can't decide whether a coincidence can also be an irony.

Comment: @SrJoven You're definitely correct about the implied time factor. I mentioned that in my post with "when there is no obvious connection other than time", but that wording is a little convoluted, so my apologies.

Comment: @janoChen The key thing to keep in mind is that irony primarily deals with contrasts or contradictions. Consider sarcasm, a form of irony. "Oh yeah, I *love* anchovies", as a sarcastic remark, the speaker is saying one thing, but means the opposite. Coincidence, on the other hand, deals with unrelated events that are made to seem related. The two can almost never be used to describe the same situation. Being that the death wish *is* connected to the interest in animal suicide, I personally would not consider it a coincidence.

Comment: @janoChen If you're writing fiction, I might suggest "Well", depending on how the character would talk. For fiction or nonfiction, consider "Strangely", "As a matter of fact", or even drop it completely and go with "It all started with" or something similar. Grammar is your oyster!

Comment: As I was heading to the doctor to get insulin, I collided with the truck that was providing insulin to the doctor. Irony. (according to that's not irony). Or, it's just an unfortunate coincidence. In which case irony never really exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it ironic by changing your second sentence.  Something like "Ironically, it began just as I finally got over my own death wish" or so.